# Microsoft Graph search files result misses path property in parentReference

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

When searching files in OneDrive for Business, the path of the parentReference is empty. Is there any reason for this limitation?

Example in [MS Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer):

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='finance')?select=name,parentReference
```

snippet from result:

```
"value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
            "name": "CR-227 Product Overview.pptx",
            "parentReference": {
                "driveId": "b!-RIj2DuyvEyV1T4NlOaMHk8XkS_I8MdFlUCq1BlcjgmhRfAj3-Z8RY2VpuvV_tpd",
                "driveType": "business",
                "id": "01BYE5RZ6TAJHXA5GMWZB2HDLD7SNEXFFU",
                "path": "/path/to/folder" <--- THIS IS MISSING
            }
        },
```

I would be glad if the path is returned because I need it. Otherwise I need to add additional overhead to query for the parent's paths.

Comment: Did you assign permission on azure portal? I am successfully got response.

Comment: Yes, I also get response. But my problem is, the path property is missing in the parentReference.

Comment: I got that, which property you looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for the parentReference.path property. I updated my example response above.

Comment: Hi see the answer as you expect , hope you are looking for that, feel free to share if you encountered any more problem.